# enable right click custom menu for images only

Tags: jquery

I have images displaying in a modal.

```
    <div class="col-md-3 img-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="image_23" name="pics[]" value="wave-2211925_640.jpg" data-id="image_23">
    <label for="image_23" style="background-image: url(uploads/wave-2211925_640.jpg)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
     </label>
    </div>
```

I want to be able to bring up a menu for whichever image is clicked. I need to get the id of the image because the right-click option should be delete and in order to delete the correct image I need the id.

I have tried this but it does not work. If I change it to a button class then it works but I can't seem to get it to work when I right click on an image.

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu context-menu">
  <li><a href="#">RELOAD</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>

$(function() {

  $(".img-box").contextmenu(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });

    $('.context-menu').hide();

    $('.context-menu').slideDown(300);

    return false;
  });

  $( ".img-box" ).click(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').slideUp(300);
  }); 
});
```

Here is the original code which works if you right click anywhere in the body.

```js
$(function() {


  $("html, body").contextmenu(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });

    $('.context-menu').hide();


    $('.context-menu').slideDown(300);

  
    return false;
  });

  $( "html, body" ).click(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%; 
  
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  
  user-select: none; 
  background-color: #2196F3; 
  color: #0D47A1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1> TRY RIGHT CLICKING </h1>

<ul class="dropdown-menu context-menu">
  <li><a href="#">RELOAD</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

img-box style:

```
#gallery .img-box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}
#gallery .img-box label i {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: green;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
}
#gallery .img-box label {
background: black;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  min-height: 150px!important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 15px;
}
#gallery .img-box input {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Update your question with more `html` , like where is `.context-menu`. make snippet.

Comment: @pedram, I have put in the snippet for the original code that I am trying to change.

Comment: Little unclear, now you trying to get `id` of image? or you trying to show this `menu` on an image. I didn't understand what you need and whats your problem.

Comment: @pedram, sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to modify the code snippet to suit what I am trying to do. I have images showing in a modal dynamically with php. Each one has a unique id. But for now, I just want to get the right click menu to appear whenever I right click on an image. The image sits in a div, `<div class="col-md-3 img-box">`

Answer (score 0):

So, according to comments and what i figured out, you need something like this, right?. if not tell me in comment to continue conversation.

```js
$(function() {


  $(".img-box").contextmenu(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });

    $('.context-menu').hide();


    $('.context-menu').slideDown(300);

  
    return false;
  });

  $( "html, body" ).click(function(e) {
    $('.context-menu').slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh; 
  width: 100%; 
  
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  
  user-select: none; 
  background-color: #2196F3; 
  color: #0D47A1;
}

#gallery .img-box {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}
#gallery .img-box label i {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: green;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 2px;
}
#gallery .img-box label {
background: black;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  min-height: 150px!important;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 15px;
}
#gallery .img-box input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="gallery">
<div class="col-md-3 img-box">
<input type="checkbox" id="image_23" name="pics[]" value="wave-2211925_640.jpg" data-id="image_23"> <label for="image_23" style="background-image: url(https://kbob.github.io/images/sample-3.jpg)"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> </label> </div>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu context-menu">
  <li><a href="#">RELOAD</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But mine does not work. Here is the contents of the whole image div. `<div class="col-md-3 img-box">
 <input type="checkbox" id="image_23" name="pics[]" value="wave-2211925_640.jpg" data-id="image_23">
 <label for="image_23" style="background-image: url(uploads/wave-2211925_640.jpg)">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
 </label>
</div>` I have also put this code into my original question which might be easier to read.

Comment: I updated answer according your code, but first, i don't understand what you trying to do with `input` and `label` and `background-image`. second, it works with your code, what's wrong exactly. you know what, until i not understand what are you trying to do with these elements and whats your problem exactly NOW cant solve your problem, tell me more.

Comment: Each image has a hidden checkbox. When an image is left clicked on, the checkbox becomes checked. It is actually an image picker. But I want to be able to delete images individually by right clicking on them and clicking delete. The code is working in your example but not on my localhost. If I right click on the image now I just get the standard browser right click options

Comment: @user8463989 if you say so, check `console log` for error. any error?

Comment: If I change .img-box to .btn then it works perfectly and shows the menu when I right click on a button. So, the code is working, just not with my .img-box class

Comment: Hmm, weird.. can you put your `.img-box` css and styles here.

Comment: Updated original question to include img.box css

Comment: I updated answer with your `css` , now see my snippet, looks bad. try to make this snippet more like your local. what should i add to see this snippet like your local? - you see, your label have not any `width` how you see your images? i just add a `width: 200px` for ex. it works fine. but in this bad view still menu works.

Comment: `display: block;` gives me width. you probably need the gallery div `<div id="gallery-body"></div>`

Comment: So add your `gallery-body` styles to you answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157223/discussion-between-user8463989-and-pedram).